# on click firing multiple times when calling a dialog box, trigger vs. click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jTree list, when I right mouse click contextmenu I display a dialog box so user may edit that item.  on this dialog box I have a table with same list of items so that user could edit more than original item picked. first time thru, upon opening dialog box, the selected item is 'selected' on the table and 'clicked' so that all its information is populated in input boxes (for the editing) - its perfect. I can even select other rows on the table and works as designed.  But I have console messages logging, the problem is when I close the dialog box and re-open it the console logs shows 10 'clicks'.  there are only 5 other clickable items on the dialog, I've commented out some of the columns to see if it was the td's, I've commented out some of the div's as well.  but always 10 'clicks'.  and all of the same clicked item.

I've found similar issues, and I've tried many of those suggestions, but still having issue.  I'm fairly new to this language.  here is some code.  thanks.

```
       BindAlertListClick();

        // this scrolls to the selected alert
        if (nodeID != "") {
            var gridContainer = $('#divAlertEditorTable')
            var scrollTo = $('tr[data-id="' + nodeID + '"]');

            gridContainer.animate({
                scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - gridContainer.offset().top + gridContainer.scrollTop()
            }, 500);

            console.log('*****trigger super-special click here')
            // 'clicks' it so it's highlighted and fields populated
            $('#divAlertEditorTable tbody tr[data-id="' + nodeID + '"]').trigger('super-special');
        }
        ...
```

and here is the function BindAlertListClick

function BindAlertListClick() {

```
$('#divAlertEditorTable > tbody > tr').off().on('click super-special', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    var alertID = $(this).attr('data-id');
    console.log('**** BindAlertListClick  alertID', alertID)
    console.log('**** $(this)', $(this))

    $('#divAlertEditorTable tbody tr').not($(this)).css('background-color', '');
    $('#divAlertEditorTable tbody tr').not($(this)).css('color', '');

    $(this).css('background-color', 'cornflowerblue');
    $(this).css('color', '#FFF');

    ...
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for your code?

Comment: @xzegga my first post... I don't think I can, it's a lot of code with a lot of pieces (full stack development).  I'm not well versed in this language so I don't know if I can reduce to a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

my team leader helped with the solution, though we still can't figure out **why** its consistently adding it 10 times.  we added the **:first** and it stops at 1.

```
$('#divAlertEditorTable tbody tr[data-id="' + nodeID + '"]:first').trigger('super-special');
```